# What would I do if an editor didn't publish my manuscript?

Tags: publications, conference, books

My paper was accepted to be published as a chapter in a SPRINGER book after it was presented at an IEEE-sponsored conference and gaining a high score form their peer-reviewers. The editor of the book series (also the chairman of the conference) invited me to submit an extended version of the paper (at least 30% of new ideas) so, I emailed the final manuscript but didn't get any feed-back until I figured out that the book is now available online but the title of my article doesn't appear in its table of contents! I asked the book editor about this issue but still haven't gotten an answer.

Comment: How long have you waited for a response from the book editor?

Comment: It's been one week now

Comment: To have a publication in a book, there is usually a deadline. Did you submit your final version within the deadline or late?

Comment: As these things go, a week is pretty short. Had it been a formatting issue you would have learned long ago, I think. If you don't get satisfaction after a bit, formally withdraw the paper for publication elsewhere. But try to get a good explanation first. Perhaps it is even a misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes of course I submitted the final version in time, except that I emailed it in LaTeX instead of in Word format, but before doing that I checked out the Springer website and found that there some LaTeX templates.

Comment: Something is unusual here.  Misunderstanding is a possibility. You should have been informed anyway, like in standard submission.

Comment: I suspect that the book editor (the conference chairman) has omitted to forward the article/chapter to Springer, knowing that this book is now published! For this reason I think she wouldn't answer me.

Comment: What's the timeline of this? When did the editor invite you, how many months later you sent a revised manuscript, how many months later you saw the book online?

Comment: The IEEE conference was held on Nov 15-18, 2017. On July 2, 2018, I was informed by email from the chairman that my article was accepted to be published as a book chapter in Springer, the deadline to submit the extended version was July 10, 2018, I emailed the final version in LaTeX in that day and afterwards I didn't receive any email neither from the chairman nor from Springer until I discovered in Feb 8 that the book is now available for sale!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your timeline, my guess is that your email didn't reach the editor. Perhaps it went into her spam folder, or he saw it and then forgot about it, etc. There's little chance this is malicious. After all, the editor has nothing to gain by holding your manuscript unpublished. Now that the book's been published, there's no chance of inserting your manuscript into it either.

You've already emailed the editor, which is all you can do. At least it'll make clear where the error was, and more optimistically, perhaps the editor will find somewhere else to publish your manuscript. It's all you can do, and next time, you can ask the editor for a confirmation of receipt if you don't hear back from her after a while.

Comment: Request a confirmation of the editor that the paper - for whatever reasons - had not been included and that you will proceed to publish it somewhere. If they do not feel that they are going to get into too much trouble with OP, they may be more willing to admit a hiccup.

Answer (score 1):

> The editor of the **book series** ... invited me to submit an extended
>   version of the paper (at least 30% of new ideas) so, I emailed the
>   final manuscript but didn't get any feed-back until I figured out that
>   **the book is now available online but the title of my article doesn't appear in its table of contents**! I asked the book editor about this
>   issue but still haven't gotten an answer.

So you are invited to submit a paper as a chapter **for a volume** in the book series. Book chapters are also reviewed (although things are easy when you are invited), and once it is accepted, the editor will tell you which volume of the book the chapter will appear.

As you haven't received any review, it is not a surprise that your paper does not appear in the **latest volume** of the book. Unlike conferences, it can take years for the chapter to appear (in my case, 2 years since it was accepted)

You see the book editor is also the program chair of some conference(s). He also has to do his own research, and likely to be a professor with teaching duties, and so on and so on. It is not unusual that he does not response to you within one week.

You can shoot him an email again, but there is nothing to worry here.

Comment: This interpretation is certainly a possibility. It is not quite clear from the OP's statements whether this interpretation is correct, or whether they were indeed invited to submit an extended version of their article *for a particular book* that is handled by the same editor as all the other books that happen to be in the same series.